# Implementing IDataErrorInfo with SubSonic 2.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, subsonic

I am moving 1 project, just the data tier, the project is using MVC 1.0 and acess mdb :S

Now I am moving to SubSonic + Sql server and all is fine, except when I try to implement to my class IDataErrorInfo for validation messages, I get always 2 times every error message

I have a table class generated by subsonic:MyTable, then I extend it.

```
public partial class myTable : IDataErrorInfo{
public string this[string columnName]{
    get{
        switch (columnName.ToUpperInvariant()){
            case "MYFIELD":
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myField)){
                    return "Incorrect MyField";
                }
                break;
            case "ANOTHER":
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myField)){
                    return "Incorrect Another";
                }
                break;
        }
        return "";
    }
}

public string Error{
    get{
        return "";
    }
}
```

}

In My Controller I add to my post action this code:

```
public class mycontroller...{
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult myAction(int id, MyTable data)
{
    try
    {
        UpdateModel(data, new[] { "MyField","Another" });
        data.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Admin");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //ViewData["Error"] = ex.Message;
        return View(data);
    }
}
```

My view have a summary generated as Html.ValidationSummary("Attention:")

When I get invalid data My summary get 2 times the error as it:

**Attention:**
Incorrect MyField
Incorrect MyField
Incorrect Another
Incorrect Another

I don't want to rewrite the validation form, here is a lot of views (about 130). I think the problem is in some place in subsonic, but I can't get where :S, Please help me :)

Best regards and thanks in advance.

no way to catch this error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of SubSonic are you using?  IIRC, Save() in v2.0.3 could call the validation method twice.

Comment: I download the source from google the latest subsonic 2.2,  just 5 days ago, and compiled it.  where is calling it 2 times the validation method ? I am going to look it, thanks.

Comment: The "bug" of the double calling was in the previous SubSonic 2.0.3

2.1 (and 2.2) don't have this.  Your problem must be something else.

Comment: Implementing this interface in latest 3.0 result in a Error in toDictionary method, I am thinking in moving me to EntityFramework.

Comment: Problem implementing Entity Framework is rewrite all my work done with Subsonic :(